# How to "jump" through folded methods

Tags: xcode

Inside a class with many methods, I like to have most of them folded (cmd + option + left arrow).

The problem I have is when I move the cursor up and down: the editor still takes into account the lines of the folded methods. In other words, I need several keystrokes to move through a folded method (instead of just one keystroke in other editors like vim for instance).

Is there an option and/or a plugin that would allow me to move through a folded method with only one keystroke ?

Answer (score 0):

If anyone is interested, I found that this plugin does the job : https://github.com/tyeen/BlockJump